# $elem.hide is not a function in angular-datatable

Tags: angularjs, npm, bower, angular-datatables

I want to use pagination plugin angular-datatable .I installed it with bower but it does n't work.It gives the below error

> TypeError: $elem.hide is not a function
>           at Object.showLoading (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular-datatables.js:698:15)
>           at postLink (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular-datatables.js:47:31)
>           at http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular.js:8783:44
>           at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular.js:8789:9)
>           at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular.js:8289:11)
>           at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular.js:7680:13)
>           at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular.js:7684:13)
>           at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular.js:7684:13)
>           at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular.js:7684:13)
>           at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular.js:7684:13)

I used  Zero configuration, 
here is the html code which i used

```html
<table datatable="" class="row-border hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Foo</td>
            <td>Bar</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>Someone</td>
            <td>Youknow</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>987</td>
            <td>Iamout</td>
            <td>Ofinspiration</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: its working kariyawasam ;) http://plnkr.co/edit/NnF2I4IMplWtIdNmRvvw?p=preview

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think you have add `javascript` files in wrong order.

you need to add in this order

1. [JQUERY](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js)
2. [ANGULAR](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js)
3. [JQUERY DATA-TABLE](https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js)
4. [ANGULAR DATA-TABLE](https://rawgit.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/v0.4.3/dist/angular-datatables.min.js)

and don't forget to add the `datatables` module to the main module as,

EX: `angular.module('plunker', ['datatables']);`

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/NnF2I4IMplWtIdNmRvvw?p=preview)

Simply - If you add the `jquery.js` after the `angular.js`, then cut the `jquery.js` and place it in top of the `angular.js`.

If you are using `bower` then update `bower.json` to meet the above changes.

Comment: i used bower.still same issue i do n't why .I added in that order.all the plugin linked properly head of the html.I am using gulp. Initialize 'datatable' in app.js

Comment: angular.module('app',[
       'pascalprecht.translate',
       'tmh.dynamicLocale',
       'ngCookies',
       'ngBootbox',
       'ui-notification',
       'dashboard',
       'bank',
       'payment',
       'userAccounts',
       'accountSettings',
       'credit-cards',
       'help',
       'contact',
       'ngDialog',
       'daterangepicker',
       'datatables'
   ]);

Comment: check the content of the page by viewing source of the page and verify all the `js` files are in proper order as in the answer. If you still get the error try to create a http://plnkr.co/edit/

Comment: glad to help you :) cheerz

Comment: I'm having the same problem and the order of js scripts are correct (angular js is in the 3rparty.js file using require('...') :  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spectrum/1.8.0/spectrum.min.js"></script>
<script src='js/modernizr.js'></script>
<script src='js/3rdparty.js'></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-datatables/0.4.3/angular-datatables.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

Also, make sure you don't have the `ng-jq` directive set to nothing. Instead you want to set it to `$` or `jQuery` i.e.

```
<html id="ng-app" ng-jq="$">
```

or

```
<html id="ng-app" ng-jq="jQuery">
```